# send android facebook message to friend using xmpp

Tags: android, facebook, message

I am looking for sending a message to facebook friend using xmpp or anything for android version.
i have fetched the list of friends now i have to send them message not a comment on their wall, mentioning clear a message in their message box.

If that user is live he will get in his chat and if offline then on his message box.

Thanks,
Gopal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a look at the Facebook SDK for Android. Edit: I see that Chat uses xmpp but the rest of the Facebook SDK doesnt. It is the same for iOS, xmpp is for chat only, so you would need to use both I believe, figure out if the user is online using xmpp if he is send the message as chat through xmpp, if he isn't send the message using the Android SDK into the message box.
SDK Links:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Chat links:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Comment: yes, but in iOS it uses xmpp, so anything like that i want to send message.

Comment: On second thought maybe facebook handles it automatically if the user is offline, the message goes into the inbox, so check the documentation.

Comment: I have used this but still i am getting error , can you find some easy stuff through which my problem can be resolved, thanks

Comment: You need to post exactly what the problem is and I am sure someone will help you. i.e code/errors etc.